# Optimize double left join in many-to-many with Doctrine

Tags: php, join, doctrine-orm, associations

In a web application I model a relation between a `Client` and a `Caregiver`. Because the relation contains information, this is modelled as two one-to-many relations (as noted in a footnote [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)).

The model is `Client <-> Relation <-> Caregiver` and to query all clients from a specific caregiver, the query builder is called like this (inside the repository of a `Client`):

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
$qb->leftJoin('c.relations', 'r')
   ->leftJoin('r.caregiver', 'ca')
   ->andWhere('ca.id = :id')
   ->setParameter('id', $caregiver->getId());

$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

**Optimizations**

This *works* at the moment. However, it seems unnecessary to join the carers as you simply could say the `r.caregiver` should match the `$caregiver` object. Unfortunately, this does not work:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
$qb->leftJoin('c.relations', 'r')
   ->andWhere('r.caregiver = :caregiver')
   ->setParameter('caregiver', $caregiver);

$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This raises a fatal error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class Entity\Carer could not be converted to string

What I want to achieve is that Doctrine matches the `r.caregiver_id` to `$caregiver_id` instead of joining the caregivers table.

**Background**

For more info, this is my (XML) mapping:

```
<entity name="Entity\Client" table="client" repository-class="Repository\Client">
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
        <generator strategy="AUTO" />
    </id>

    <one-to-many field="relations" target-entity="Entity\Relation" mapped-by="client" />
</entity>

<entity name="Entity\Relation" table="relation">
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
        <generator strategy="AUTO" />
    </id>

    <many-to-one field="caregiver" target-entity="Entity\Caregiver" inversed-by="relations">
        <join-column name="caregiver_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
    </many-to-one>

    <many-to-one field="client" target-entity="Entity\Client" inversed-by="relations">
        <join-column name="client_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
    </many-to-one>
</entity>

<entity name="Entity\Caregiver" table="caregiver">
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
        <generator strategy="AUTO" />
    </id>

    <one-to-many field="relations" target-entity="Entity\Relation" mapped-by="caregiver" />
</entity>
```

**Question**

How can I remove the second join from the query builder such that MySQL joins only the relation table and not the caregivers table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want this...

```
->setParameter('caregiver', $caregiver);
```

...to use the Caregiver `id`. Right now it's setting the `caregiver` parameter to the entity object, which causes the error you see.

So how about this:

```
->setParameter('caregiver', $caregiver->getId());
```

This of course assumes you have an 'id' getter method in your Caregiver entity. You may need to do `$caregiver->id` instead depending on how you usually access your entity data.

Comment: It's stupid I haven't tried that! Thanks, this works. I couldn't find this thing in the Doctrine manual, is it mentioned somewhere?

Comment: Not sure about the manual. Just going by the error you got, it's clear that Doctrine is expecting a simple value instead of an object when mapping parameters.

Comment: It's because [Doctrine says](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-your-query) this: "Calling setParameter() automatically infers which type you are setting as value. This works for integers, arrays of strings/integers, DateTime instances and for managed entities." (and the caregiver is a managed entity) :) Anyhow, doesn't really matter now!